# Django get static media files

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views, django-settings

All, i am using Django1.4,i have  a question regarding accessing the img files,js files etc... I have my files in the directory /opt/lab/labsite/media/img for images and /opt/lab/labsite/media/js for javascript files.What should i change the settings in the setting files such that the below html works..I am using django server to run the code

My code is currently located in /opt/lab/labsite/settings.py and other modules lies in /opt/lab/labsite/.........

```
 <img src="/media/img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" />
```

Below are the settings in the settings.py file

```
 # Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
 # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
 MEDIA_ROOT = '/opt/lab/labsite/media/'

 # URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
 # trailing slash.
 # Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
 MEDIA_URL = ''

 # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
 # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
 # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
 # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
 STATIC_ROOT = ''

 # URL prefix for static files.
 # Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
 STATIC_URL = '/opt/lab/labsite/media/'
```

`Changes`

```
  MEDIA_ROOT = '/opt/lab/labsite/media/'

  MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

  STATIC_ROOT = '/opt/lab/labsite/static/'

  STATIC_URL = '/static/'

  STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  )

  # List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
  # various locations.
  STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
      'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
      'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
  #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
  )

  TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
      'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
      'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
  #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
  )

  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
      'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  )

  ROOT_URLCONF = 'labsite.urls'

  # Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
  WSGI_APPLICATION = 'labssite.wsgi.application'

  TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
      # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
      # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
      # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
     '/opt/lab/labsite/templates'
  )

  INSTALLED_APPS = (
      'django.contrib.auth',
      'django.contrib.admin',
      'django.contrib.contenttypes',
      'django.contrib.sessions',
      'django.contrib.sites',
      'django.contrib.messages',
      'django.contrib.staticfiles',
      'home',
      # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
      # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
  )

  # A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
  # performed by this configuration is to send an email to
  # the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
  # See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
  # more details on how to customize your logging configuration.

  TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
     'django.core.context_processors.static',
     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'
  )
```

HTML:

```
 <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/hi.png" alt="Hi!" />
 <img src="/static/img/hi.png" alt="Hi!" />
 <img src="/media/img/hi.png" alt="Hi!" />
 <img alt="Hi!" src="/opt/ilabs/ilabs_site/media/img/hi.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STATIC_URL` you have set doesn't look good. I think that should be `STATIC_ROOT`.

You should set (for example) `MEDIA_URL='/media/'` and `STATIC_URL='/static/'` and I hope you have also enabled static file serving in urls.py

Comment: i had missed the settings in urls.py and that fixed the issue.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set this in settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/opt/html/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/opt/lab/labsite/static/',
)
```

add this in context processors:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    ...
)
```

and don't forget this in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

and then:

```
<img src="/static/img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" />
```

or

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL}}img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" />
```

if `logo.jpg` is located in `/opt/lab/labsite/static/img/`

In addition, `STATIC_ROOT` serves as a static folder to be served by Web servers/reverse proxies like Apache, Nginx, etc. If you invoke:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This will copy all files from `/opt/lab/labsite/static/` to `STATIC_ROOT` - `/opt/html/static/`. This is useful for deployments.

But all this is for development. For production there are better ways to serve static content - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#staticfiles-production

Comment: As stated: `# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.` - this is a directory for uploads, with the corresponding permissions. This should be different than the STATIC_URL/STATIC_ROOT, as it is supposed that files will be uploaded there. So you can set it accordingly, in case when you really have such functionality to upload content. Otherwise - just leave it empty. To use it - you'll also need the `django.core.context_processors.media` template processor.

Comment: There is no such settings as TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in django 1.4 should i include it...

Comment: Yes, you should. Don't forget that it is a tuple: `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)`

Comment: I have added the settings as u indicated and still i do not see the images i also verified the image path..i have create a file as /static in /opt/lab/labsite/static/mg/hi.png .Please do see the changes in the question i indicated

Comment: I've updated my answer - actually `django.core.context_processors.static` serves from `STATICFILES_DIRS` and not from `STATIC_ROOT`. `STATIC_ROOT` is intended for use by external servers/proxies, when used with `collectstatic`. And you do not need modifications in 'urls.py' to use the scenario above with `STATICFILES_DIRS`.